# if statement not working with database

Tags: php

Why isn't this code working?

```
$welcome = mysql_query("SELECT welcome FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "'");

if($welcome == '0')
{
echo 'register is 0';
}
else
{
echo 'register is 1';
}
```

`$_SESSION['user']['id']` returns as 1, by the way.

Comment: We cannot help you, Brooke, with as little data as you've provided. You must debug this further yourself. What is the result of `SELECT welcome FROM users WHERE id = '1'`? Are you sure you want to be quoting that id?

Comment: Isn't it obv what i'm trying to do...

Comment: Maybe because the username is `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--`.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - Nearly five minutes it took for you to post LBT? You're getting slow ;)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL returns a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) on success, false on error, not a value from the query. Try this:

```
$welcome = mysql_query("SELECT welcome FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($welcome);
if($row['welcome']== '0')
{
echo 'register is 0';
}
else
{
echo 'register is 1';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't build your query like that as you'll not be protected from a SQL Injection Attack.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT welcome FROM users WHERE id = %d", $_SESSION['user']['id']);
// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Once that has finished you then need to fetch from the result, you cannot just query it.

```
if(!$result)
  echo "Error"; // Deal with it
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['welcome'];
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL documentation, the resource is returned if the select statement is successful, or 'false' if the statement fails. 
Although there's a better, more secure way to achieve what you are trying to accomplish, your statement can be revised simply to :

```
if($welcome === false)
{
  echo 'register is 0';
}
else
{
  echo 'register is 1';
}
```

That will work, but as I said earlier, the whole code needs to be updated to a more secure version.